# GO : debug/verbose logging for SSL Handshake

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I have a client written in Go that is talking to a server with mTLS enabled. I'd like to capture the messages during SSL handshake on the client side. Something similar to what this option provides with Java : `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`

Go client code:

```
transport, err := getHttpTransport()
httpClient := pester.New()
httpClient.Transport = transport
httpClient.Timeout = timeout
httpClient.MaxRetries = int(maxRetries)
httpClient.Backoff = pester.ExponentialJitterBackoff
response, connectionErr := httpClient.Do(request)

func getHttpTransport() (*http.Transport, error) {
    certFile := CACertFile
    certBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
    tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(certBytes) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Not a valid cert %v", certFile)
    }

    var certificates []tls.Certificate
    clientCert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(ClientCert,ClientKey)
    certificates = []tls.Certificate{clientCert}

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{RootCAs: certPool,
        Certificates:       certificates,
        MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
        InsecureSkipVerify: !enableMTLS}

    tr.TLSClientConfig = tlsConfig

    return tr, nil
}
```